# Special characters from UNIX not being read properly by Java

Tags: java, unix, character-encoding

I have a Java application wherein a string is being read from a file in UNIX. Then, the string is being passed to another application using URL POST method. However, it is having problems when there are special characters such as:

~
^
[
]
\
{
}
|

I am constructing the URL using a StringBuilder:

```
new StringBuilder() .append("message=").append(message).toString()
```

Is there a standard on how these characters should be encoded from UNIX to Java? I believe this is the issue here.

Comment: share the code and the sample data file on question..

Comment: The ones in the question seem ASCII characters. Is the problem for ASCII characters?

Comment: @AjinkyaPatil  The sample data file contains this string 'TEST ~ ^ [ ] \ { } |' and it is being fetched by a FileReader. This string is then passed to another application using URL POST method. I believe this is where the problem lies.

Comment: This question is off-topic without a [MCVE].

Comment: (FWIW I'm guessing that this has nothing to do with any "unix to Java" conversion and it's just a case of not constructing the POST URL properly).

Comment: @davmac         I see. Apologies for the confusion. I am constructing the URL using a StringBuilder

new StringBuilder()
.append("message=").append(message)
.toString()

Comment: @JustineAguas this kind of detail needs to be in the question. Once more, you need an [MCVE]. _Post minimal code_ which exhibits the problem. _Edit the question_ so that it contains this and any other pertinent details. Do not add details via comments.

Answer (score 1):

Those are characters used for a **regular expression**.

So somewhere you place the string in a position where a regex is expected.

- replaceFirst
- replaceAll instead of replace
- split
- format
- printf

Encoding cannot be the error here (normal ASCII functions). However be aware that FileReader is an old utility class that reads a file with the default platform encoding.
When the file is in a known encoding, say UTF-8, better do:

```
Path path = file.toPath();
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly read characters from a file in Java you need to specify the character set. E.g. like this (error handling left out for brevity):

```
String charset = "UTF-8"; // replace with what you are really using in your Unix system
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset);
// use the reader...
```

Comment: The characters shows by OP are plain ASCII ones (codes below 127). They should get same code whatever encoding is used.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ever heard about EBCDIC?

Comment: @Henry I would postulate that the chance that OP's file is encoded in EBCDIC is vanishingly small.

Comment: @Henry: I forgot that one... I really do not think that OP actually uses EBCDIC, but your are right, my comment is bad. It should be *They should get same code in all common encodings - only now less used ones such as EBCDIC are not ASCII extensions*

Answer (score 0):

A URL requires that certain characters be encoded. This is nothing to do with Unix, or Java; it is part of the specification for URLs.

In Java, you can encode arbitrary text to make it suitable for URLs via the `URLEncoder.encode` method:

```
new StringBuilder()
        .append("message=")
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8"))
        .toString()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I notice that when I concatenate the string to other strings, I am having problems again.

For example
String message = "TEST ~ ^ [ ] \ { } |"; 

it works

But when I try

String message = "TEST ~ ^ [ ] \ { } |" + message2;

it doesn't work

Comment: @JustineAguas as I said in comments on your question above, your question needs to be complete. I can't see what is wrong with your code from the small parts of it you supply. You need to prove a [MCVE].